# MongoDB Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 35.156.235.216:27017

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

trying to connect mongoose to my express app and getting this error:

```
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Listening to the port 5000
connect ECONNREFUSED 35.156.235.216:27017
```

Im connecting the app directly to MongoDB Atlas, everything was working fine yesterday but this morning i got this Error. Here is the db connection file:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

require("dotenv").config();

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
    console.log("connected to MongoDB..");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
};
```

Comment: can you post process.env.MONGO_URI?

Comment: MongoURI: mongodb+srv://royals-ecom:<password>@cluster0-dr95c.mongodb.net/Royals?retryWrites=true&w=majority